# Mestre-detalhe em MVC C# com Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pessoal estou precisando montar um cadastro mestre-detalhe. 
Já pesquisei e vi alguns exemplos na internet, porém como eu faço para quando o mestre não estiver cadastrado, os detalhes forem armazenados de forma temporária para na gravação geral salvar o registro mestre e os registros detalhe.

Pensei em fazer em Session, mas acho que isto pode dar algum problema. Existe alguma solução para isto?

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int ClienteID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
}

public class Telefone
{
    [Key]
    public int TelefoneID { get; set; }                
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

A ideia é fazer algo parecido com a imagem abaixo, porém sem a necessidade de o Cliente cadastrado no banco de dados. Fazer tudo em só post.

A grande dúvida, é como eu posso "gravar" os dados do telefone e retornar para a tela essa informação sem fazer refresh...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que é um cadastro mestre-detalhe?

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira Acredito que deve ser alguma entidade do sistema dele, e detalhe provavelmente mais detalhes. De qualquer forma, não está claro. Essa pergunta deve ser reformulada.

Comment: Mestre-Detalhe, quer dizer um registro pai com vários filhos. Exemplo, Cliente (mestre) e Telefone (detalhe). Somente encontrei exemplos com o mestre salvo, não salvando tudo em um único post.

Comment: @marlon.tiedt, pode ser mais claro em sua dúvida? Se puder isolá-la em código, tanto melhor.

Comment: Se você tem o modelo Cliente e o modelo Telefone, não vejo dificuldade em aplicar o modelo... Um simples `<input type="hidden" />` com valor `0` se for um cliente novo ou o valor de ID do `Cliente` se for uma atualização resolveria seu problema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Já que é para salvar tudo de uma só vez, eu usaria uma **abordagem client, sem postback** até o momento em que tudo tiver de ser salvo.

Você poderia argumentar sobre a possível perda de dados em cadastros complexos, em que o usuário sem querer fecha o browser, mas usando os recursos do HTML 5 (se isso for uma opção) você pode salvar os dados em `localstorage` ou usando um DB client (websql) o que evita tal perda de dados.

### Exemplo funcional:

Código da view:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Controllers.MasterDetailObj
<html>
<head>
    <title>Postar master/detail</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#add").on("click", function () {
                var tel = $("#numero").val();
                var ddd = $("#ddd").val();
                var idx = $("#telefones > tbody > tr").length;
                $("#telefones > tbody").append("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='Telefones[" + idx + "].Numero' value='" + tel + "' />" + tel
                    + "</td><td><input type='hidden' name='Telefones[" + idx + "].Ddd' value='" + ddd + "' />" + ddd + "</td></tr>");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Postar master/detail</h2>

    <div>
        <div>
            <label for="numero">Número</label>
            <input type="text" id="numero" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="ddd">DDD</label>
            <input type="text" id="ddd" />
        </div>
        <button id="add">Add</button>
    </div>

    @using (this.Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Nome)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Nome)
        </div>
        <table id="telefones">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Número</th>
                    <th>Ddd</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Código do controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult MultiDetailSubmit()
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MultiDetailSubmit(MasterDetailObj obj)
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // aqui estarão disponíveis todos os itens adicionados na lista de telefones no client

            return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return this.View(obj);
    }

}
```

Models:

```
public class MasterDetailObj
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public List<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
}

public class Telefone
{
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Ddd { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: mas como eu iria guardar os itens dos telefones na View e depois recuperar no controller?

Comment: No botão de Add você adiciona uma nova linha na tabela, e para cada campo a ser enviado para o servidor cria um `<input type='hidden'>` com o valor a ser enviado. Se você adicionar vários valores, com o mesmo atributo name poderá recebê-los no servidor na forma de array.

Comment: É mesmo, tinha esquecido isto. No meu caso o name seria "Telefones" estou certo? e se for um elemento complexo? Exemplo se tive-se DDD e Telefone como deveria proceder com o elemento input?

Comment: Nesse caso pode receber um array de objetos complexos na action (e.g. `class Telefone { public string Telefone {get;set;} public string DDD {get;set;} }`), e na página renderizar os inputs com o `name` usando o padrão `[0].Telefone`, `[0].DDD` para o telefone-0, `[1].Telefone` e `[1].DDD` para o telefone-1, e assim por diante.

Comment: Você poderia passar um exemplo de como ficaria o a view e controller? Assim quem tiver a mesma dúvida que eu, já vai ver a resposta completa. Grato

Comment: Claro... estava trabalhando nisso! =)

Comment: Postei um exemplo de como fazer... você vai notar que o script gera `Telefones[0].Numero` ao invés de simplesmente `[0].Numero` como falei anteriormente... isso decorre do fato de o model não ser uma símples lista, mas sim dados do master junto com dados dos vários detais.

Comment: Nota: se você implementar exclusão de registros, terá de renomear os inputs de forma que os índices fiquem em ordem. Se pular do `Telefones[0].Numero` direto para o `Telefones[4].Numeros`, então não vai funcionar. Não pode conter saltos.

Comment: Miguel sua resposta ficou bem clara, pode me fazer uma breve explicação, e na hora de editar? aonde tem que carregar novamente essa lista, como é feito?

Answer (score 5):

> Esse código foi escrito na época que o Entity Framework estava na versão 5, então possivelmente a lógica de manipulação da coleção de telefones pode ter mudado. Por favor, me notifique por comentários se alguma condição de erro for encontrada para que eu corrija.

Utilize o pacote `BeginCollectionItem`, disponível no NuGet:

> http://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/

O tutorial a seguir documenta bem como implementar o mestre-detalhe:

http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/07/24/asp-net-mvc-2-client-side-validation-for-dynamic-fields-added-with-ajax/

Ficaria assim:

### _CreateOrEdit.cshtml (Cliente)

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.Cliente

@* Demais campos do seu model *@

@if (Model != null && Model.Telefones != null)
{
    foreach (var telefone in Model.Telefones)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_TelefonesEditor", telefone);
    }
}

@* Botões de submit, fechamento de <fieldset>, etc. *@
```

### _TelefonesEditor.cshtml

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.Telefone

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Telefones"))
{ 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TelefoneID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClienteID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefone)
}
```

### ClientesController.cs

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Controllers
{
    public class ClientesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Cliente cliente)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (shop.Telefones != null)
                {
                    foreach (var telefone in cliente.Telefones)
                    {
                        telefone.ClienteID = cliente.ClienteID;
                        context.Entry(telefone).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Lógica adicional, caso Model não seja válido
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Cliente cliente)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Telefones Originais
                List<Telefones> telefonesOriginais = context.Telefones.AsNoTracking().Where(t => t.ClienteID == cliente.ClienteID).ToList();

                if (cliente.Telefones != null)
                {
                    // Telefones Excluídos
                    foreach (var telefone in telefonesOriginais)
                    {
                        if (!cliente.Telefones.Where(t => t.TelefoneID == telefone.telefoneID).Any())
                        {
                            var telefoneExcluido = context.Telefones.Single(t => t.TelefoneID == telefone.TelefoneID);
                            context.Telefones.Remove(telefoneExcluido);
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }

                    // Telefones Novos ou Editados
                    foreach (var telefone in cliente.Telefones)
                    {
                        if (telefone.ClienteID == 0)
                        {
                            telefone.ClienteID = cliente.ClienteID;
                            context.Telefones.Add(telefone);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.Entry(telefone).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        }

                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

                context.Entry(cliente).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Lógica adicional, caso Model não seja válido
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: era isto mesmo que estou procurando. Vou testar para ver se me atende. Você saberia me dizer qual o termo para pesquisar o tema em inglês. Vi que biblioteca que você passou faz um tempo que não tem atualização...Valeu pela dica...

Comment: O termo que você pode usar para pesquisa é `BeginCollectionItem tutorial`. Este link que eu te passei é o mais completo como tutorial. Há também perguntas no Stack Overflow gringo que podem ajudar. Agora que tem um pouco de código, posso melhorar a resposta. Vou ver se faço isso logo.

Comment: @marlon.tiedt Veja se a lógica serve pra você agora.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez depois de muito tentar entender esse plugin kkk consegui kkkk, mas fiquei com uma dúvida na ali no método de Editar, onde tem um comentário "telefones excluidos" a condição telefone.Id == telefone.Id, é sempre verdadeira, e ele remove...Aí abaixo, a Condição ClienteId =0 é falsa, quando vai editar, da erro, pois acabou de excluir anteriormente

Comment: @Rod Verdade, estava com erro. Esse código eu fiz pra EF5. Possivelmente no EF6 não precise tantas verificações. É preciso testar e ir arrumando.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez mas qual seria o ponto que me falaria se o telefone foi deletado? o Editar, add, tudo certo, problema que eu não tenho como parametrizar se foi deletado

Comment: @Rod Tem sim. Você vai ao banco e pega todos os valores originais, comparando com o que veio da tela. Separa todos arqueles que não vieram da tela e exclui no contexto.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez consegui =D finalmente kkkkkk agora espero que não fique lento, se eu mandar uma lista muito grande... tem alguma dica?

Comment: Acho que só fica lento se forem muitos registros **mesmo**, tipo 1000 registros, mas aí acredito que seja mais fácil travar o JS que o EF.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez entendi, outra coisa, que percebi, é que as msgs de validação no Cliente não funcionam...pois para funcionar o ID e o Name, devem ser os mesmos...existe alguma solução ?

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo você utilizar o padrão MVVM, em especial o KnockoutJS, ele é um ótimo pacote onde traz sua model para a view e com base nele você consegue ter essa implementação da lista. O mais legal de trabalhar com ele é que você pode optar por transacionar o objeto final ou parte dele.

Segue abaixo alguns links extremamente úteis para o conhecimento e ver a implementação do KnockoutJS com o MVC

[MVC-4-Knockout-CRUD](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MVC-4-Knockout-CRUD-fa818bdb)

[Building with MVVM](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/08/21/building-javascript-mvvm-apps-in-asp-net-mvc-using-knockoutjs.aspx)

[KnockoutJS and bootstrap](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/knockout-js-and-bootstrap-with-asp-net-mvc-part-1)

[Introduction to KnockoutJS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/learning-knockout-part-1-introduction-to-knockout-js-and-cr/)

E claro como não podia faltar, o link do próprio KnockoutJS

[KnockoutJS Official](http://knockoutjs.com/)

(Disponível no Nugget tbm [Install-Package KnockoutJS])