# Práticas recomendadas para Inserção, Alteração e Exclusão com EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Para exclusão de registros talvez não tenha, mas para Inserção e Alteração eu acredito que já deve existir algo discutido.

Provavelmente, a maior prática recomendada sobre Inserção e Alteração seja a das ***ViewModel´s***, onde você criando uma view adequada para cada caso, terá então os dados de forma simples para fazer uma Inserção, precisando apenas passar os dados da ***ViewModel*** para o **Domínio**.

Não quero incentivar e nem pedir conselhos sobre práticas ruins,  mas sempre é bom detalhes bem esclarecidos, e ainda assim podem existir muitos casos simples de ***ViewModel´s*** ou casos em que um Domínio é simples quanto ao nosso caso de necessidade de uma ***ViewModel*** que decidirmos por não replicar uma classe.

Bom, um exemplo:

**Pessoa**:

```cs
public class Pessoa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyString = false)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Pessoa")]
    public virtual ICollection<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
}
```

**Telefone**:

```cs
public class Telefone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TipoTelefone TipoTelefone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(3)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyString = false)]
    public string Ddd { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyString = false)]
    public string Numero { get; set; }
}
```

E então temos uma View para cadastro de pessoas que permite você inserir números de telefones, e com isso temos alguns casos:

1. Pode existir números já cadastrados (caso de edição);
2. Pode-se inserir novos números (caso de inserção ou edição);
3. Pode-se remover alguns números e até adicionar outros (casos de edição).

Obs: Acredito ter listado todas.

Em casos de edição pode até ser simples, basta deixar a propriedade `Telefones` de `Pessoa` alimentado e então adicionar o banco de dados.

**Mas para inserção**, uma pergunta: O `Id` de pessoa será passado diretamente para `Telefones` e então esse simples exemplo de inserção cadastra a `Pessoa` e os `Telefones`?

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Pessoa model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        dbContext.Pessoas.Add(model);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Para alteração: O que é recomendado fazer para então satisfazer as possiveis condições apresentadas?

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Pessoa model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var entry = dbContext.Pessoas.Find(model.Id);
        if (entry != null)
        {
            dbContext.Entry(Pessoa).CurrentValues.SetValues(model); // ???
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // E se:
            // 1. Existir números já cadastrados?
            // 2. Inserir novos números e outros já existiam?
            // 3. Alguns números e adicionar outros?
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Pessoa não encontrada!");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Quais as práticas recomendadas nestes cenários, que acredito ser bem genérico e explicativo para diversos casos?

**Detalhe**: Mesmo exemplificando com ***ASP.NET MVC***, responde à outros tipos e projetos também.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Introdução

Antes de mais nada, é preciso [entender como funciona a implementação do DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx), que não é mencionado em nenhuma resposta sobre o assunto. Ele supõe que as variáveis em tela podem ser simples (primitivas: `int`, `float`, `String`, `bool`...) ou complexas (um objeto dentro de outro, uma coleção dentro de outra). É esta classe que realiza a associação dos Ids e nomes dos campos do seu formulário com os objetos que são recebidos pelo *Controller*.

O Mestre-Detalhe, para o [`DefaultModelBinder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder(v=vs.118).aspx), é um objeto (mestre) que possui dentro de si uma `Collection` de objetos de outro tipo (ou, dependendo, até do mesmo tipo do mestre). Você, inclusive, [pode implementar o seu próprio `ModelBinder`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/806415/Model-Binding-using-IModelBinder-and-DefaultModelB), se quiser, mas não creio que seja necessario, até porque o `DefaltModelBinder` é excelente para a maioria das situações.

## Um exemplo na mão

Vamos fazer uma implementação manual de um mestre-detalhe. Suponha um objeto chamado `Jovem` e sua coleção de `Brinquedos`:

```
public class Jovem
{
    [Key]
    public int JovemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    pubic virtual ICollection<Brinquedo> Brinquedos { get; set; }
}

public class Brinquedo
{
    [Key]
    public int BrinquedoId { get; set; }
    public int JovemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual Jovem Jovem { get; set; }
}
```

Queremos que o mesmo formulário insira um `Jovem` e pelo menos um `Brinquedo` para o `Jovem`. Então o formulário fica mais ou menos assim:

> Estou usando Bootstrap com Font Awesome para exemplificar.

```
@using SistemaDeJovens.Resources
@model SistemaDeJovens.Models.Jovem

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Cadastro de Jovem</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Preste atenção nesse atributo -->
        <input type="hidden" name="Brinquedos.index" autocomplete="off" value="0">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Brinquedos[0].Nome" class="control-label col-md-2" />
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="Brinquedos[0].Nome" id="Brinquedos_0__Nome" class="form-control ckeditor" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Brinquedos[0].Nome" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Criar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.FontAwesomeActionLink("Voltar para Index", "Index", "fa-list", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
</div>
```

Repare que coloquei tudo fixo, mais um atributo chamado "index". Por que ele existe? [O Steve Sanderson explica que o `ModelBinder` precisa dele pra saber o que vai ser associado ao objeto detalhe](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) (repare que isso não é nenhuma novidade, é coisa do MVC2). Ele não precisa ser inteiro. Nos meus projetos, por exemplo, "index" é sempre um [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx).

E por que coloquei tudo fixo? Porque os *Helpers Html* são incapazes de gerar o Html no formato dos índices que são necessários pra que o `ModelBinder` faça a interpretação correta do seu formulário.

No artigo já citado, o Steve Sanderson também explica a dificuldade de fazer isso na mão, e por isso que foi criado o pacote NuGet que insisto tanto pra vocês usarem: [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/).

## Exemplos do BeginCollectionItemHelper

Já abordei o assunto nessas respostas:

- [Mestre-detalhe em MVC C# com Razor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8746/mestre-detalhe-em-mvc-c-com-razor/8749#8749)
- [Editar lista de objetos com POST do form em MVC C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30451/editar-lista-de-objetos-com-post-do-form-em-mvc-c/30457#30457)

## Perguntas

---

### O Id de pessoa será passado diretamente para Telefones e então esse simples exemplo de inserção cadastra a Pessoa e os Telefones?

No caso da inserção, se você tem um *Model* `Pessoa` ainda não salvo com uma *Collection* `Telefones`, no caso do Entity Framework 6, o objeto `Pessoa` será salvo antes, ganhará um Id, e logo após cada `Telefone` será inserido. Não é preciso fazer atribuições.

No caso do Entity Framework 5, ainda pode ser necessário atribuir mais algumas informações aos objetos de `Telefone`, porque o framework ainda não era muito espertinho pra ler e salvar objetos agregados como faz o Entity Framework 6.

### O que é recomendado fazer para então satisfazer as possiveis condições apresentadas?

1. Existir números já cadastrados?

   Se o número está sendo cadastrado em repetição, você pode buscar antes os telefones (utilizando `AsNoTracking()` para evitar o monitoramento pelo contexto) e iterar a lista que vem do formulário com a lista que veio do banco de dados.
2. Inserir novos números e outros já existiam?

   Basta inserir os números novos. As respostas já mencionadas dão exemplos de como fazer isso.
3. Alguns números e adicionar outros?

   Acredito que seja um dos dois casos acima.

### Quais as práticas recomendadas nestes cenários, que acredito ser bem genérico e explicativo para diversos casos?

Não tem muito segredo: as verificações normalmente ficam na edição do registro pai, e nunca na inserção. O que se pode olhar na inserção são números duplicados, inválidos, etc.

Comment: Esse BeginCollectionItem não ficaria muito bom, aonde possui inúmeros campos, além de só poder deixar eles tudo lado a lado, horizontalmente, pelo menos é os exemplos que vejo... muitos dados ficaria uma view muito feia kkk, mas no caso do Tiago, só 3 propriedades, de boa

Comment: @Rod Totalmente errado isso que você falou. O BeginCollectionItem é um **facilitador** de tratamento de dados de entidades dependentes. Ter mais ou menos campos não muda nada em questão de comportamento do componente. De qualquer forma, vou melhorar essa resposta quando puder (dentro ainda do período de recompensa).