# Como criar formulário mestre-detalhe utilizando um ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Tenho um *viewmodel* em meu projeto. Dentro dele tenho duas entidades que são uma lista de itens.

Estou fazendo a lógica de edição de dados dessas entidades que estão dentro do *viewmodel*. Tenho 5 entidades ao todo. As que não são uma lista, eu consigo popular os dados nos campos repectivos na *view*, agora, as que são lista eu não consigo. Consigo carregar o objeto e preenchê-lo, mas não consigo passar esses dados para a *view*.

Os códigos que tenho são:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        CliCliente cliente = db.CliCliente.Find(id);
        AnaAnamineseAlimentar anamnese = db.AnaAnamineseAlimentar.Find(id);
        RecRecordatorio recordatorio = db.RecRecordatorio.Find(id);
        List<RefRefeicao> refeicao = anamnese.RefRefeicao; //db.RefRefeicao.Find(id);
        List<QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar> qfa = anamnese.QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar;//= db.QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar.Find(id);

        for (int i = 0; i < qfa.Count; i++)
        {
            qfa[i].AnaId = anamnese.AnaId;
            qfa[i].AnaAnamineseAlimentar = anamnese;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < refeicao.Count; i++)
        {
            refeicao[i].AnaId = anamnese.AnaId;
            refeicao[i].AnaAnamineseAlimentar = anamnese;
        }

        AnamineseViewModel viewModel = new AnamineseViewModel() 
        {
            CliCliente = cliente,
            AnaAnamineseAlimentar = anamnese,
            RecRecordatorio = recordatorio,
            RefRefeicao = refeicao,
            QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar = qfa
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Na *view*:

```
@model NutriSport.Models.AnamineseViewModel

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <br />

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <table class="table">

        <tr class="success">
            <th>
                Tipo
            </th>

            <th>
                Horário/Local
            </th>

            <th>
                Alimentos/Quantidades
            </th>
        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i <= Model.RefRefeicao.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr class="success">

                <td>
                    @Html.TextBox(string.Format("RefRefeicao[{0}].RefTipo", i), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.TextBox(string.Format("RefRefeicao[{0}].RefHorarioLocal", i), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.TextArea(string.Format("RefRefeicao[{0}].RefAlimentosQuantidades", i), null,  new { @class = "form-control" })
                </td>
            </tr> 
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade você consegue passar os dados para a *View* sim. O problema é outro: você está tentando montar um formulário mestre-detalhe e possivelmente não está ficando do jeito que precisa ficar.

O princípio da montagem está correto. Falta incrementar a inteligência do seu código para que o formulário faça sentido.

Se é um formulário, você precisa anotá-lo como um, ou seja:

```
@model NutriSport.Models.AnamineseViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <br />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        ...
```

O próximo detalhe está em como você escreve o formulário. Você fez da forma que é correta, porém desnecessariamente trabalhosa. Além disso, para funcionar certinho o *binding* deste formulário, você precisaria indicar ao *binder* que o atual registro se trata do *index* `i`. Ou seja:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i <= Model.RefRefeicao.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr class="success">
            <input type="hidden" name="RefRefeicao.index" id="RefRefeicao_index" value="@i.ToString()" /> @* Isto aqui *@
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox(string.Format("RefRefeicao[{0}].RefTipo", i), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.TextBox(string.Format("RefRefeicao[{0}].RefHorarioLocal", i), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.TextArea(string.Format("RefRefeicao[{0}].RefAlimentosQuantidades", i), null,  new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
        </tr> 
    }
```

Feito isso, o *Model Binder* identifica corretamente seu elemento como um objeto da classe agregada `RefRefeicao`.

Só que, como já disse algumas vezes, [existe um componente que resolve isto para você](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem). [Já falei sobre ele muitas e muitas vezes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+begincollectionitem). Com ele, você pode montar sua lista para o formulário da seguinte forma:

```
    @foreach (var refeicao in Model.RefRefeicao)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Refeicoes", refeicao)
    }
```

Neste caso, você precisa criar uma *Partial* que terá o seguinte conteúdo:

### `_Refeicoes.cshtml`

```
    @model NutriSport.Models.RefRefeicao

    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("RefRefeicao")) @* O nome precisa ser o mesmo que você definiu a List<RefRefeicao> no ViewModel *@
    {
        <tr class="success">
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RefTipo), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RefHorarioLocal, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.RefAlimentosQuantidades, i), null,  new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
        </tr> 
    }
```

O componente cria o `index` pra você. Você não precisa fazer mais nada.

Se tudo foi feito certo, ao enviar seu `<form>` para o *Controller* que recebe `AnamineseViewModel` por `[HttpPost]`, você verá que `RefRefeicao` estará apropriadamente preenchido.

Comment: Colocarndo o `<input type="hidden" name="RefRefeicao.index" id="RefRefeicao_index" value="@i.ToString()" />` não funcionou. =(

Comment: O que não funcionou? A geração da tag? O envio do formulário? O preenchimento? [Veja esta resposta, em que é feito manual](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38188/pr%C3%A1ticas-recomendadas-para-inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-exclus%C3%A3o-com-entityframework/38192#38192).

Comment: O preenchimento dos dados... Os campos continuam em branco..  Os dados são enviados, mas continuam em branco. =(

Comment: Ah, bom. Naturalmente que vão ficar em branco, porque sua abordagem, usando `@Html.TextBox`, não define valores (o valor é o segundo parâmetro, no qual você está passando `null` para todos). Por tentativa e erro não vai funcionar mesmo.

Comment: Como eu poderia resolver essa situação? Colocando os inputs no html puro ao inves de usar razor? Ou da pra resolver usando o razor?

Comment: Bom, se eu comentei do `null`, que ele representa o valor, substituindo o `null` pelo valor irá naturalmente aparecer o `input` preenchido.

Comment: Mas tipo, sendo uma lista, como eu poderia substituir esse valor?

Comment: Elemento a elemento, jovem. Dentro do `foreach`, exatamente como você estava fazendo para escrever o nome de cada `input`.

Comment: Eu tentei e não deu certo.. Coloquei como string: `@Html.TextBox(string.Format("RefRefeicao[{0}].RefTipo", i), string.Format("RefRefeicao[{0}].RefTipo", i), new { @class = "form-control" })` e não funciona.. =(.. O que é mostrado é RefRefeicao[{n}].RefTipo