# Normalização de tabelas e Relacionamentos

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, normalização

Estou começando um projeto do zero e no meio da modelagem do banco, tive um problema. Ao construir os *models*, não consegui fazer do jeito certo e acabei por me confundir todo.

Tenho informações de alunos, ocorrências e logins. Onde tenho várias ocorrências para um aluno e várias ocorrências para um login, para rastrear que login esta gerando a ocorrência.

Mas eis o meu problema: em minha tabela de alunos tenho várias informações como nome do aluno, nome do pai, nome da mãe, nome do responsável, telefone de contato, telefone principal, telefone de contato e telefone alternativo.

Pensei em colocar o nome dos pais em uma tabela diferente, assim como os telefones, para deixar as tabelas com suas respectivas objeções, assuntos. Ou seja, organizar os assuntos. Mas, ao fazer dessa forma, me gerou vários erros ao fazer  o *scaffolding*, pois de primeira só aparecia como *dropdown* um telefone e somente o nome do pai. Então esta faltando dados.

Como que eu faria? Deixaria todas as informações em uma tabela só? Ou seja, eliminaria essas tabelas de telefones e pais, e deixaria essas informações em uma tabela só, a de alunos? Ou não, separar está certo, criando essas duas tabelas? E como eu faria?

Os *models*:

## Aluno

```
 //Aqui começa a declaração normal dos atributos
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string TipoEnsino { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

    public DateTime AnoLetivo { get; set; }

    public int Ano { get; set; }

    public string Turma { get; set; }

    public int NumeroChamada { get; set; }

    public string Foto { get; set; }

    public string Observacoes { get; set; }
    //Aqui termina 

    //Aqui começa os relacionamentos

        //Ocorrencias
        public ICollection<Ocorrencia> Ocorrencias { get; set; }

        //Pais
        public long PaisId { get; set; }
        public Pais Pais { get; set; }

        //Telefone
        public long TelefoneId { get; set; }
        public Telefone Telefone { get; set; }
    //Aqui termina
```

## Pais

```
 //Aqui começa a declaração normal dos atributos
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string NomePai { get; set; }

    public string NomeMae { get; set; }

    public string NomeResponsavel { get; set; }
    //Aqui termina a declaração

    //Aqui começa os relacionamentos

        //Aluno
        public long AlunoId { get; set; }
        public Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
    //Aqui termina
```

## Telefone

```
//Aqui começa a declaração normal de atributos
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Contato { get; set; }

    public string Alternativo { get; set; }

    public string Responsavel { get; set; }
    //Aqui termina a declaração normal

    //Aqui começa os relacionamentos

        //Aluno
        public long AlunoId { get; set; }
        public Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
    //Aqui termina
```

Comment: Seria interessante inserir a mensagem de erro completa na pergunta e se possível suas classes de modelo e views.

Comment: Então cara, o que acontece é que eu mexi aqui no código e ficou uma bagunça. Mas tive erros de relacionamento, onde o Entity não sabia onde começava ou terminava e depois tive erros de migrations, devido as alterações que fiz. Mas o que me intriga é: Como que eu monto a tabela aluno ? Separa essas informações, tipo nome dos pais e telefones, em um tabela diferente, ou deixo tudo numa tabela só, ou seja, a de aluno ? Porque da maneira que fiz, não dei certo. Fiz as tabelas pais e telefones e relacionei 1-1 com a tabela aluno. E ai isso me gerou uma view com dropdowns. E não é isso que queria...

Comment: Você pode colocar na pergunta seus Models, mesmo que eles estejam bagunçados?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez alteração feita ! Desculpe a demora. Mas esses são os models que estão me dando dor de cabeça.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não vejo a necessidade de separar a informação de Pais de Aluno, a não ser que você queira fazer uma tabela de Responsáveis, cuja cardinalidade para Aluno seja 1 pra N.

Em todo caso, vou supor que você apenas quer cadastrar pai e mãe, então a entidade `Aluno` fica assim:

```
[DisplayColumn("Nome")]
public class Aluno 
{
    [Key]
    public long AlunoId { get; set; }

    public TipoEnsino TipoEnsino { get; set; } //TipoEnsino é um Enum

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

    public DateTime AnoLetivo { get; set; }

    public int Ano { get; set; }

    public string Turma { get; set; }

    public int NumeroChamada { get; set; }

    public string Foto { get; set; }

    public string NomePai { get; set; }

    public string NomeMae { get; set; }

    public string NomeResponsavel { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ArquivoFoto { get; set; }

    public string Observacoes { get; set; }

    //Ocorrencias
    public virtual ICollection<Ocorrencia> Ocorrencias { get; set; }

    //Telefone
    public virtual ICollection<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
}
```

Telefone alterei para cardinalidade N:

```
[DisplayColumn("Numero")]
public class Telefone 
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public TipoTelefone TipoTelefone { get; set; }

    public string Numero { get; set; }

    //Aluno
    public long AlunoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Então dessa forma, eu poderia cadastrar vários telefones certo ? Pra esclarecer: esse TipoTelefone seria um Enum também certo ? E eu não precisaria criar um _Controller_ pra fazer as manipulações de telefone, certo ? Ou teria ?

Comment: Sim, você poderia cadastrar quantos telefones quiser. `TipoTelefone` é um Enum. No seu caso ele pode ter 3 valores: Contato, Alternativo e Responsavel. A manipulação de telefones você pode fazer no próprio *Controller* de Aluno. Posso indicar respostas minhas em que tem essa manipulação bem explicada.

Comment: Poxa, seria muito bom se pudesse indicar essas respostas. Pois fazendo no _Controller_ do aluno ficaria muito mais fácil pra mim e economizaria tempo ! :)

Comment: O resumido está aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38188/pr%C3%A1ticas-recomendadas-para-inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-exclus%C3%A3o-com-entityframework/38192#38192

Comment: Cigano, eu vi os links e tal. Mas não consegui visualizar direito. Eu teria que, além de instalar o pacote, mexer tanto no controller, tanto na view ? Será que tinha como colocar um exemplo de código dessa forma nesse meu contexto ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8746/mestre-detalhe-em-mvc-c-com-razor/8749#8749

Comment: Então se eu fizer da forma que tá nessa resposta, isso vai funcionar certo ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Vai. Apenas coloque `Aluno` no lugar de `Cliente`. A lógica é a mesma.

Comment: Tranquilo então. Vou fazer aqui, caso eu tenha algum tipo de erro eu volto !

Comment: Cigano, nesse trecho 'if (shop.Telefones != null)' esse _shop_ representa que atributo ? O cliente ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Isso.

Comment: Cigano, tive problemas aqui... A partial não aparece de forma alguma... Fui inspecionar a página aqui e não aparece nem o código referente a partial..

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Acho que está na hora de uma nova pergunta, não?

Comment: Você acha melhor ?

Comment: Com certeza. Olha o tamanho dessa lista de comentários. Já estamos em outro assunto que não necessariamente está dentro do escopo da pergunta. Melhor separar.

Comment: Beleza, já já posto o link aqui da pergunta !

Comment: Cigano, o link aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39055/partial-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-renderizada

Answer (score 5):

Em relação a isso, como o Cigano disse, a não ser que os alunos não tenham o relacionamento com pais e sim com responsáveis. Se for apenas pais, sabemos que uma pessoa só pode ter 1 pai e 1 mãe (em tese), portanto poderia deixar as informações de cada um junto a informação do Aluno. Sobre os telefones, pela relação ser de 1 para n tenho costume de ver em inúmeras aplicações o uso de uma tabela externa tanto para telefone quanto para e-mail

Comment: Nossa cara, muito boa sua explicação também. Além da resposta do Cigano, a tua me ajudou muito a entender melhor essa parte de normalização !